# How can i make sort for data table by ngx-order-pipe

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I have JSON data from API displayed in a table and I want to do sort for a table header,

I tried to use **ngx-order-pipe** but I face this error:

> TypeError: expression.indexOf is not a function

this my **template**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-fixed-header">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>الاسم</th>
            <th>الهاتف</th>
            <th>العنوان</th>
            <th>الحساب</th>
            <th>ملاحظات</th>
            <th>إجراءات
                <button class="btn btn-success">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </button>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of clients | filter:term | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 2, currentPage: p } | orderBy:clients:true">
            <td>{{item.id}} </td>
            <td>{{item.name}} </td>
            <td>{{item.phone}} </td>
            <td>{{item.address}} </td>
            <td>{{item.account}} </td>
            <td>{{item.nots}} </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <button class='btn btn-info'>
                    <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger">
                    <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this the decomentition for **ngx-order-pipe** https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-order-pipe

So are there anything I missed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inputs for the pipe are the expression string, reverse boolean and some others. You made a mistake in providing the former.

If you want to sort by id, it should be :

```
orderBy : 'id' : true
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, in fact still not working because I want to sort all of the table header can you help me to understand it?

Comment: @MohamedElkast You want to sort based on each header??

Comment: yes, I got it, it's working now thanks a lot for your cooperation.

Comment: I have a little issue:  the sort working now normally in every page of table pagination as separated but I want to do sort in all data in API or DB

Comment: If you are paginating in client side, there won't be any problem. Else if it is in server, you can't just use the pipe. You have to sort it from the server itself while fetching data.

Comment: Yes the pagination on the client-side, can you advise me how I do it in the best technique?

Comment: @MohamedElkast I assume you have the entire data at client side. So the order and pagination pipes will automatically format the data i.e. the array will be sorted first and then paginated. I have implemented the same use case for one of my projects and it worked fine.